# ModelState.IsValid returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In a ASP.NET MVC 5 application, the following code should send the user back the the original view if `ModelState` validation fails.

The user will be presented with the error messages relevant to the inputs which failed validation.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(DemoViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);

    ...

    return RedirectToAction("Details");
}
```

However, Currently, when my `ModelState` is invalid, I get a 400 Bad Request Error page:

**IE**
[image: IE]

**Chrome**
[image: Chrome]

Initially, I assumed this was a miss-configuration of custom error pages.
To rule this out, I created a new project with the same error page configuration and I could not re-create the problem.

Just for reference, here is the error config:

*Web.config customerrors*

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/500.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
    <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/401.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/401.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />      
</customErrors>
```

*Web.config httpErrors*

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
    <remove statusCode="401" />
    <error statusCode="401" path="401.html" responseMode="File" />
    <remove statusCode="403" />
    <error statusCode="403" path="401.html" responseMode="File" />
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File"/>
    <remove statusCode="500" />
    <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
```

What could have broken how the `ModelState` is processed?

Comment: Put break point on IF condition and see the code block is debugged or not. May be your code not reachable

Comment: is there is any view with name "Edit"..????

Comment: @Kartikeya Yes, the view is present an available.

Comment: @sangramparmar A break point on the `if` statement gets hit and that the code is reachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of my problem.

The page causing the error had 2 forms, one which is only visible in a modal, and the main form I was trying to debug.
I had mistakenly thought that the main form was the one causing the problem, when actually, it was the hidden form which was to be displayed in a modal.

After extensive debugging, I found a stray line of code in another action, and not the one I thought was causing the problem.

Thanks to those who offered suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You are firing a GET request at your controller action, but it expects a POST. this is resulting in an error code 400.

You might want to redirect to your Edit action which is displaying the object you want to edit.

Assuming you have an Id in your ViewModel and your Edit action expects an `int Id`, do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(DemoViewModel model)
{
    int modelId = model.Id;
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
       //call the Edit action which displays the item .. or details. 
       //Not an ActionResult decorated as [HttpPost]!
       return RedirectToAction("EditGetAction", new { id = modelId });
    }

    ...

    return RedirectToAction("Details");
}
```

Comment: I see why you are suggesting this, and I will double check that I am sending a POST.  However, I'm not sure about the redirect to the `Edit` action on an Invalid ModelSate. The invalid elements will not be retained when the view is rendered. I will double check that I am issuing a POST request.

Comment: I am definitely sending a `POST` request. The method is explicitly set using `FormMethod.Post` on the `BeginForm` Html Helper in my view.  I have also verified that a `POST` request is being sent using developer tools within IE & Chrome using the 'Network' tracing tool.

Comment: Have you confirmed this with Fiddler or any other proxy, which method with which Httpverb the line `if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);` calls?